# Student's $t_\nu$ distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, book-recommendation, descriptive-statistics

Can anyone help me to solve the exercise $(4.6.9)$ from Nitis Mukhopadyay book ?
I do not know even how to begin the transformation technique suggested. I'm interested  in the derivation of $(11.4.11)$
from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170328/generic-constant-and-student-d-f) question.

**EDIT:**
There are 2 snippets under this question : page 238 showing exercise 4.6.9. which I would like to see solved. On the second snippets is the definition of Pearson correlation coefficient $r$ in 4.6.7. My problem is dated back to the beginning of the exercise 4.6.9. which I'm unable even to start solving.

[image]

where $r$ is given by $(4.3.7)$

**SECOND SNIPPET**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I've obtained (please see the 3rd snippet below) the required solution **but** for the fact that I've obtained an extra factor
$\frac{1}{(n-2)}$
please see the very last circled question mark there.
as opposed to Wanted [=Chceme in Czech].

Dictionary for you to my manuscript:
Chceme=Wanted
Vzorec=Formula
Obecne=In general

Could you please point me to the place at which I must have an error ?

[image]

Comment: Why down-voting rather than giving a hint ?

Comment: Maybe because your actual question appears nowhere on this page? Maybe because you have not explained the relevance of the long 'snippets' from the text? Maybe you have not shown what you have tried?

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for your hints. They are better than mere down-voting. There are 2 snippets under my OQ : page 238 showing exercise 4.6.9. which I would like to see solved. On the second snippets is the definition of Pearson correlation coefficient $r$ in 4.6.7. My problem is dated back to the beginning of the exercise 4.6.9. which I'm unable even to start solving. If I had improved my Q, please up-vote so that my Q is not going to be closed.

Comment: @BruceET I've now added the 3rd snippet with my best attempt to solve the exercise 4.6.9. Could you up-vote now ? Thank you.

Comment: Your photocopies of your work are rather hard to decipher.  Please always type your work into the question field directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the second to last line. The exponent of $n-2$ should be $-\frac 12$, i.e. $(n-2)^{-\frac 12}$ because there is already a factor of $n-2$ in the third to last line, therefore you should not multiply by $(n-2)^{\frac 32}(n-2)^{-\frac 32}$ but $(n-2)^{\frac 12}(n-2)^{-\frac 12}$. To povede k odpovědi.

Comment: Both, your answer and your Czech is good. Thank you.